# HTML Page on Local vs Server Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am having an issue with the way my page appears on the server compared how it is working locally on my computer. Here is the code I am using: http://pastebin.com/pbDbNsNU -- There are no console errors, nor are there any issues with the code when displayed locally.

Once put on the server: http://devtherrd.com/thank-you/mortgage-lending.html  -- you'll notice my footer's right hand side columns are completely gone. This only happens once put on server, but I am not sure why this could be happening since these are basic social media links and newsletter form. The same footer is working throughout the entire site, except for all my files within the /thank-you folder structure.

What recommendations do you for me. If there is missing information please let me know I can provide, I apologize in advance for my complete noob posting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen, the file which you uploaded on your server is incomplete.
It doesnot have the code to display that part. But the code you provided on pastebin works fine. So update the html file on the server. Your problem should be fixed.

Comment: You are correct, I am missing code on my server side.

To figure out why this was happening I tested out a couple of situation and here is what is the problem. The moment I remove the PHP code under Recent Post, all the code appears on the server.

Comment: I figured out the issue by placing "../" right before my PHP code.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help. LOL, i didn't know you were using php. So i suggesting the copy paste. Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Validate your code with:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdevtherrd.com%2Fthank-you%2Fmortgage-lending.html

There are HTML errors.

Comment: I did not know of this tool's existence, I appreciate for the introduction as this is very useful for me.